# EntitySet 'SelectListItems' is based on type 'SelectListItem' that has no keys defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

## Controller

```
 public JsonResult menulist()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Session["User_Type"].ToString() != null)
                {
                    var menu = db.menuitems.ToList().Where(d => d.HasAccess.Contains(Session["User_Type"].ToString())).OrderBy(d=>d.Name);
                    return new JsonResult { Data = menu, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
                }
                return new JsonResult { Data = "", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new JsonResult { Data = "", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
        }
```

## Model

```
public class MenuItem
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int MenuItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool Disable { get; set; }
        public string HasAccess { get; set; }
        public int ParentMenuId { get; set; }
    }
```

## Context

```
public DbSet<MenuItem> menuitems { get; set; }
```

I have auto generated `MenuItemId` field in my database, so I have defined it in my model as key and as identity. still I am getting an error of `Key not defined` and 'SelectListItem' has no key defined.

Error

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   Demo.Context.SelectListItem: : EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   SelectListItems: EntityType: EntitySet 'SelectListItems' is based on type 'SelectListItem' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this ?

```
var menu = db.menuitems.Where(d => d.HasAccess.Contains(Session["User_Type"].ToString())).OrderBy(d=>d.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Its not working. Problem remains as it is. actually m having problem related modelvalidation. To resolve that I have applied key in my model. but couldnt resolve that issue

Comment: @Priya, Can you please show the code where actually you are using `SelectListItem` or else tell at which line exception is being thrown ?

Comment: exception is thrown while i am communicating with db in controller. `db.menuitems.ToList()` is actually throwing exception

Comment: @Priya, does this model has relationship defined with another table in DB ? Please post your `DataContext` code.

Comment: No, It does not have any dependency on other table

Comment: @Priya, Can you please show your `DataContext` code ? i.e `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method.